# android- changing custom listview background for some of rows

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to change background color of each row on my listview .I'm using a custom listview .

each row has a RelativeLayout and I change it like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ........
if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.rl=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl);
                holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
         holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_vip);
}}
```

I don't change every row's bakcground , I just change some of them .

I wanted to know is it a bad idea? I mean , does it consume lots of memory and it's bad for performance ?

thanks

Comment: try to change background base on position or set particular background  flag in each list item data and set base on this flag value.

Comment: @HareshChhelana thanks for the reply ,can you see the next answer ? is this what you mean ? if so , I've added a comment of the problem ,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can change Background Color of `ListView` Row from `getView()` Based on `Position`.
    Put this code in Your `getView()` Method. i have used position `% 4` for repeating color after `4th item`

```
    switch (position % 4) {
        case 0:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case 1:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 2:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 3:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

If You have Fix items in ListView then You can also change color according to position

```
        if(position == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else if(position == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else if(position == 2) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        } else if(position == 3) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply , it changes background color of listview's row  , as I said , I've a custom layout . in a row , I've a linearLayout with white background color, so When I did what you said,it changed background color of row but I need to change background color of linearLayout . How can I do so ?

Comment: @mohsen see my answer below

Comment: I think this works...                                      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout); then set color to linear layout  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

Comment: @RajeshJadav  the code I sent is working , the question is , is it a bad way to do this ? is it consuming memory and is it bad for performance ?

Comment: no it is not consuming more memory beacuase of viewholder pattern you used in your adapter

Comment: try to change background base on position

Comment: it consumes more memory if you have not used viewholder

Answer (score 3):

Your drawable name state that you have two types of drawables `roundcorner and round_corner_vip` so I think you have to set a vip `flag` as @Haresh Chhelana said in the comments, then in your adapter class `getView()` you should do something like that:

```
if(vip_flag)
{
  holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_vip);
}
else
{
  holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
} 
// or put some more else-if conditions and set background according to conditions.
```